# for remove() function index out of range error

Tags: python

I am getting "index out of range" error while executing this code. Please help me with this.

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,5,6,4,3,2,5,5,5,5,5,5]

for i in range(len(arr)):
    for j in range(i+1,len(arr)):
        if (arr[i]==arr[j]):
            arr.remove(arr[j])
```

Comment: Index out of range means you are trying to access an index in the array that does not exist in the array.  indexes start at 0 in most languages, so if you try to access the index at the "length" of the array, you will always get out of range errors. Try length-1.

Comment: thank you soo much for ur replay

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your code runs, it removes a few elements, but the `len(arr)` in the for loops is not updated since it will be assigned in the first run and it will stay constant until it goes out of scope

Use a while loop to fix this issue

```
arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,5,6,4,3,2,5,5,5,5,5,5]

i = 0
while i < len(arr):
  j = i + 1
  while j < len(arr):
     if arr[i] == arr[j]:
        del arr[j]
     else:
        j += 1
  i += 1
print(arr)
```

Output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: thank you soo much for ur replay

Comment: can you accept my answer if this helped?

Comment: yes,accepted but answer is partially correct.Code is not working.Could you please try one more time.

Comment: if you can give details on what you are trying to achieve, i can assist you

Comment: Iam trying to delete duplicates from the list.There are other ways to remove but why this is not working.

Comment: done, i have added a fix

Comment: Yes it's working now.Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

if you wish to remove elements that repeat themselves, you can use `set(arr)`

Comment: thank you soo much for ur replay